# Conditional subsetting in R based on a value in another data frame

Tags: r, subset

I want to subset a data frame based on a value in another data frame (*that's the easy part*). On top of that, I wish to tell R that if the value in the second df is above certain level, then the subset should consist of all the values in the first df.
That's a mouthful, so here's an example:

DF1 looks like this:

```
|   date    |  value |
----------------------
| Jul 1     |  1     |
| Jul 2     |  2     |
| Jul 3     |  3     |
| Jul 4     |  4     |
```

For simplicity let's say DF2 looks like this

```
value=99
df2<-data.frame(value)
```

Again, I want to tell R that if the value in df2 is above 5, then the subset of df1 should contain values 1,2,3,4.

Here's what I'm trying that does not work:

```
subset(df1, value %in% ifelse(df2$value[1]>5, c(1,2,3,4), df2$value[1]))
```

Can you help, please?
Also, additional points if you could explain why is the above code not working.

Cheers!

Comment: In the code that you tried, should `values` be `value`?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. Just fixed it. It's not the source of the problem, though.

Comment: Another problem is in ifelse: the test is an (atomic) logical (TRUE or FALSE), while the (presumably expected, but failing) result is a vector of length 4: ? ifelse: "ifelse(test, yes, no): Value: A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Martin . I understand that the ifelse part is what breaks the chain. Can you suggest how to make it work?

Comment: I still don't understand the real aim of this computation, but does this do the trick? I simply expanded the ifelse to an if ... else construction and applied a temporary variable:

if(df2$value[1]>5) temp <- c(1,2,3,4) else temp <- value; 
subset(df1, value %in% temp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me

```
subset(df1, value %in% (if (df2$value[1]>99)  c(0,1,2,3) else (df2$value[1])))
```

did the magic.

Answer (score 2):

How about plain old if() rather than ifelse().

For example:

```
if(F) c(1:4) else 99 # returns 99
if(T) c(1:4) else 99 # returns vector c(1:4)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I've just figured it out myself ;) Cheers!